# ajax not working disabled duplicate data in select tag and <a>

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

i want to be disabled duplicate options in my dropdown but my jquery are not working.
I query sql when I select type and I want to disable select tag of member if data in database duplicate value in select tag

test.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="types"> Type:</label> 
<select id="types" name="types">
 <option></option>
 <option value="Top">Top</option>
 <option value="Button">Button</option>
 <option value="Inner">Inner</option>
 <option value="Outer">Outer</option>
</select>

<select id="member" name="member">
  <option value="1">1</option> 
  <option value="2">2</option> 
  <option value="3">3</option> 
</select>

<p id = "datalist">aa</p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#types").change(function(e){
            $("#datalist").empty();
            $.ajax({
                method:"post",
                url:"/livesearch",
                data:{types:$("#types").val()},
                success:function(res){
                    var data = "";
                    $.each(res,function(index,value){
                        // data += '<a class="tg">'+value.types+'</a>';
                        data += '<a class="tg1">'+value.member+'</a>';
                    });
                    data += "";
                    $("#datalist").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
var y = [];
$('.tg1').each(function() {
y.push($(this).text());
});

$('#member').find('option').each(function() {
var x = $(this).val();
if (y.includes(x)) {
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
}
});

</script>
```

python code

```py
@app.route("/test")
def test():
    return render_template("/test/test.html")
@app.route("/livesearch",methods=["POST","GET"])
def livesearch():
    searchbox = request.form.get("types")
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    query = "select * from testDB where types LIKE '{}%' order by types".format(searchbox)
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return jsonify(result)
```

it's possible to edit my code to disabled duplicate options

Comment: Perhaps `select distinct member`?

Comment: Hi, change your js code like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4ke3dsgu/) .